# Find all objects in second array that have the specified properties as an object in the first array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Say I have two arrays of objects.

```
const arr1 = [
  {
    id: '5f6d8fe8f13352002abe77c5',
    subject: 'ray@example.com',
    location: 'Location 2',
    timestamp: '2020-08-30T18:00:23.000Z',
  },
  {
    id: '5f6dacdb49b4bf002a94c73f',
    subject: 'ray@example.com',
    location: 'Location 3',
    timestamp: '2020-08-30T18:00:23.000Z',
  },
];

const arr2 = [
  {
    id: '5f6d8fc3f13352002abe77c1',
    subject: 'john.doe@example.com',
    location: '101 Dirk Place',
    timestamp: '2020-08-31T18:00:23.000Z',
  },
  {
    id: '5f6d8fd9f13352002abe77c3',
    subject: 'jane.doe@example.com',
    location: 'Location 1',
    timestamp: '2020-08-30T18:00:23.000Z',
  },
  {
    id: '5f6d8fe8f13352002abe77c5',
    subject: 'ray@example.com',
    location: 'Location 2',
    timestamp: '2020-08-30T18:00:23.000Z',
  },
  {
    id: '5f6d99c4f45312002af7e343',
    subject: 'john@example.com',
    location: 'Location 2',
    timestamp: '2020-08-30T18:00:23.000Z',
  },
  {
    id: '5f6d99e41edf47002acd3292',
    subject: 'johno@example.com',
    location: 'Location 3',
    timestamp: '2020-08-30T18:00:23.000Z',
  },
  {
    id: '5f6dacdb49b4bf002a94c73f',
    subject: 'ray@example.com',
    location: 'Location 3',
    timestamp: '2020-08-30T18:00:23.000Z',
  },
  {
    id: '5f6d9e9794a701002a6f9924',
    subject: 'Marcia14@hotmail.com',
    location: 'Bedfordshire kwhlm5 Awesome Concrete Shoes Co',
    timestamp: '2020-08-01T23:05:00.000Z',
  },
]
```

How do I get all items in arr2 that have the same location as one of the items in arr1 (i.e. have either 'Location 2' or 'Location 3'), but have a different subject (i.e. does not return items in arr2 that have a subject property of 'ray@example.com'). Preferably through the use of Javascript array functions (map, forEach, filter etc.)

The returned array should be

```
  const arr3 = [
  {
    id: '5f6d99c4f45312002af7e343',
    subject: 'john@example.com',
    location: 'Location 2',
    timestamp: '2020-08-30T18:00:23.000Z',
  },
  {
    id: '5f6d99e41edf47002acd3292',
    subject: 'johno@example.com',
    location: 'Location 3',
    timestamp: '2020-08-30T18:00:23.000Z',
  },
]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would extract from the first array the properties you are interested in (i.e. location and subject) using the [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method, and then, filter the second array using the [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method with the extracted properties (included or not(!) included) using the [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method.

```js
const arr1 = [{"id":"5f6d8fe8f13352002abe77c5","subject":"ray@example.com","location":"Location 2","timestamp":"2020-08-30T18:00:23.000Z"},{"id":"5f6dacdb49b4bf002a94c73f","subject":"ray@example.com","location":"Location 3","timestamp":"2020-08-30T18:00:23.000Z"}];
const arr2 = [{"id":"5f6d8fc3f13352002abe77c1","subject":"john.doe@example.com","location":"101 Dirk Place","timestamp":"2020-08-31T18:00:23.000Z"},{"id":"5f6d8fd9f13352002abe77c3","subject":"jane.doe@example.com","location":"Location 1","timestamp":"2020-08-30T18:00:23.000Z"},{"id":"5f6d8fe8f13352002abe77c5","subject":"ray@example.com","location":"Location 2","timestamp":"2020-08-30T18:00:23.000Z"},{"id":"5f6d99c4f45312002af7e343","subject":"john@example.com","location":"Location 2","timestamp":"2020-08-30T18:00:23.000Z"},{"id":"5f6d99e41edf47002acd3292","subject":"johno@example.com","location":"Location 3","timestamp":"2020-08-30T18:00:23.000Z"},{"id":"5f6dacdb49b4bf002a94c73f","subject":"ray@example.com","location":"Location 3","timestamp":"2020-08-30T18:00:23.000Z"},{"id":"5f6d9e9794a701002a6f9924","subject":"Marcia14@hotmail.com","location":"Bedfordshire kwhlm5 Awesome Concrete Shoes Co","timestamp":"2020-08-01T23:05:00.000Z"}];

const locations = arr1.map(item => item.location);
const subjects = arr1.map(item => item.subject);
const filteredArray = arr2.filter(
    item => locations.includes(item.location) && !subjects.includes(item.subject)
);

console.log(filteredArray);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks! Clean solution!